# Convergence of sequence if convergence of subsequence (Basic)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and one of its subsequence $b_m = a_{n_m}$ where $(n_m \in \mathbb{N})_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a strictly increasing sequence.

I am beginner in analysis and want to ask if the following proof is valid for the statement: "if a subsequence converges, then the (parent) sequence also converges"

Let $b_m = a_{n_m}$ be a convergent subsequence, with $\lim b_m = L$. So that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $M$ such that for all $m > M$, we have $|b_m - L | < \epsilon$. This implies $|a_{n_m} - L| < \epsilon$ for all $m > M$. Since $n_m$ is a strictly increasing sequence, we have that for all $m > M$, we have $n_m > n_M$. So $|a_{n} - L| < \epsilon$ for all $n > n_M$.

I am not sure about this last line. Does $|a_{n_m} - L| < \epsilon$ for all $n_m > n_M$ imply $|a_{n} - L| < \epsilon$ for all $n > n_M$?

Comment: It's not a proof and you're right about the last line not holding (you've found the problem). It's not true that every sequence with convergent subsequence converges.

Comment: For example: sequence $a_n=(-1)^n$ isn't convergent, but it has 2 convergent subsequences $(a_{2k})$ and $(a_{2k+1})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct. It could not possibly be correct, since the statement is false: if $a_n=(-1)^n$, then the subsequence $(a_{2n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$  converges, but $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ doesn't. And the error lies, in fact, in the line that you mentioned. You have no basis whatsoever to assert that$$n>n_M\implies\lvert a_n-L\rvert<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: how about $|a_{n_m} - L| < \epsilon$ for all $n_m > n_M$ imply $|a_{n} - L| < \epsilon$ for all $n > n_{M+1}$

Comment: It *doesn't* imply that. Why are you trying to prove a statement that you know that it is false?

Comment: what is the 'closest' true statement to this?

Comment: If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$, then, for every subsequence $(a_{n_m})_{m\in\mathbb N}$ of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, $\lim_{m\to\infty}a_{m_n}=L$.

Comment: okay thanks. The one I was looking for was this: "If every subsequence of a given sequence of real numbers is convergent, then the sequence is convergent." which is trivial. Just a blunder on my part. I would want to delete this question.

Comment: Why? If I knew that you would delete it, I would have not provided an answer.

Comment: I am not deleting it. I just think this question was a blunder.